# How do I draw pixel-perfect symmetrical elliptical shapes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'm in the process of drawing a large envelope path on a large 12"×16" graphic.  Forgive me, but I'm new to Inkscape.  I'm having problems with drawing perfectly symmetrical pixel-perfect precise shapes.  My cursor is bouncing all over the place, and I can't seem to figure out how to set up my grid in which each intersection is an integer, and also how to get my cursor to snap to these grid intersections…

I'm assuming I need to set up my grid and snap to grid setting better.  But I'm not really sure how to achieve my desired result.

1. My graphic is 12"×16".  How to set up a grid so that I can snap my cursor to the exact integer points?  I can't keep my cursor steady enough to get precise enough ending points.  For example, I need 12.0, and not 12.7:

[image]

2. How can I easily determine the center of the shape, and then again,  keep my cursor snapping to equal integer endpoints on the X axis?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Wyatt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the Document Properties has all units set to pixels, and in Preferences also set the grid units to pixels.

[image]

Then switch on the **Snap to Grids** option, **Snap Nodes, Paths, Handles**, and **Snap Guides**, and **Enable Snapping**, in the Snap Control Bar.

Place some guides to help you get the measurements you need.

Then draw the shape you want with the Bézier tool.

For example:

[image]

Comment: This worked pixel-perfectly.  Thank you for your help.  This helped me immensely.  Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 1):

One method, and likely not the only method, is to place guides at the desired locations, using both horizontal and vertical guidelines.

- Drag your mouse from the ruler bar at the top, downward. This will place a guideline at the point you release the mouse button. Observe your cursor as it passes over the guideline. When it changes color, double click. If it is a horizontal line, the Y coordinate will be highlighted, allowing you to precisely set the location.
- Do the same from the ruler bar at the left, dragging to the right. Set its location to the point you require.

Ignore the tiny circular feature of the guidelines, as they are reference points for angled lines and not applicable to this question.

Once you have the lines placed, your cursor will snap to the intersection of the guides when creating a path.

For the midpoint, the same applies, although you don't have to have a horizontal guide. Use either the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (I forget which) to constrain your mouse movement to the orthogonal while changing the curve.